# Laravel: simplexml_load_file not working

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xpath, simplexml

I'm new to Laravel. I created a Controller-function that reads an xml file in my public (/xml) folder and searches it for a node with a specific id-attribute.

```
public function show_word($id)
{
    $xml_path = asset('xml/words.xml');

    $xml_sim = simplexml_load_file($xml_path);
    $word_existing = $xml_sim->xpath("//word[@id=" . $id . "]");

    return view('glossarium.vocab_morph', compact('word_existing'));
}
```

However, when I call the Route with the ID, I get a timeout-error (Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded).
My checklist:

- SimpleXML is enabled in my PHP configuration: Do I need to enable it
  somehow within Laravel?
- I tried using backslashes - no success.
- I cannot return the $xml_sim variable- timeout as well.
- I can view the xml-file in the browser. Is it possible that laravel cannot access the file somehow?

Can you help me out?

Comment: How big is the `words.xml` file?

Comment: Only 6KB, but there is way more to come :)

Comment: This isn't a Laravel issue really. It's just standard PHP stuff. What happens if you try `dd(file_get_contents(asset('xm/words.xml')));` in the first line of the function? That wil tell you if there is a permission issue.

Comment: I get the same problem ... it's loading ... and loading ... and loading. Reading the file works in vanilla php and it is well formed. Reading another xml-file doesn't work either....

Comment: Can you show the route you have setup? And the URL you call?

Comment: I kept simplifying the route, so currently this is my route: Route::get('/bla', 'NomenController@show_xml'); My url-call: http://localhost:8000/bla

Comment: Well when you call `localhost:8000/bla/123` to pass an ID, that route won't match. Change your route to `Route::get('/bla/{id?}', 'NomenController@show_xml`);`

Comment: yep, but I'm currently not requiring any $id variable. My current method: `public function show_xml()
     {
         $xml_path = asset('xml/words.xml');
         $xml_sim = simplexml_load_file($xml_path);
        return dd($xml_sim);
     }`

Comment: Artisan gives me : `[Fri Dec  2 21:08:27 2016] ::1:50599 [200]: /xml/la_words.xml` so I guess there is no permission issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I used the wrong helper-function.
I moved my xml to the laravel resources folder and access the path with the function

```
$path = resource_path('xml/words.xml');
```

Thanks nonetheless for your help!